# How to write a json schema using oneof for this json data

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

JSON data

```
{
  "alert_details": {
    "event_date": "2021-04-26T12:30:80Z",
    "camount": "789",
    "profile": {
        "name": {
           "first_name": "xxxx",
           "last_name": "xxxx",
           "middle_name": "xxx"
        }
    },
    "check_cash_date": "2021-04-26",
    "profile_address": {
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "street_address": "xxxxxx",
      "city": "xxxx",
      "state": "CA",
      "zip_code": "90021"
    },
   "alert_id": {
      "id": "abc123",
      "subject": "abc123",
      "abc_id": "abc123"
    }
  },
  "alert_sub_type": "check change",
  "alert_type": "change",
  "provider": "ABCD",
  "view_date": "2020-11-03T10:15:30Z",
  "status": "Read"
}
```

and

```
{
  "alert_details": {
    "event_date": "2020-11-03T10:15:30Z",
    "account_number": "*********xxx",
    "check_start_number": "2",
    "myprofile": {
        "name": {
           "first_name": "xxxx",
           "last_name": "xxxx",
           "middle_name": "M"
        }
    },
    "order_shipped_date": "2021-04-23",
    "myprofile_address": {
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "street_address": "xxxxx",
      "city": "xxxx",
      "state": "xxxx",
      "zip_code": "90021"
    },
    "quantity_ordered": "12",
    "alert_id": {
      "id": "abc123",
      "subject": "abc123",
      "abc_id": "abc123"
    }
  },
  "alert_sub_type": "review Check",
  "alert_type": "review",
  "provider": "abcd",
  "view_date": "2020-11-03T10:15:30Z",
  "status": "Read"
}
```

not understanding how to use the **oneof** and create a schema using this payload, I am new to writing the schema using oneof , I have written this schema using oneof:

```
  {
    "description" : "schema validating people and vehicles",
    "type" : "object",
    "oneOf": [
            { "$ref":"#/definitions/checkchange" },
            { "$ref":"#/definitions/reviewcheck" }
        ],
      
     "definitions": {
       "checkchange":{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "alert_details": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/AlertDetails"
            },
            "alert_sub_type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "alert_type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "provider": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "view_date": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "alert_details",
            "alert_sub_type",
            "alert_type",
            "provider",
            "status",
            "view_date"
        ],
        "title": "Welcome4"
    },
    "AlertDetails": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "event_date": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "camount": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "integer"
            },
            "profile": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Profile"
            },
            "check_cash_date": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
            },
            "profile_address": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/ProfileAddress"
            },
            "alert_id": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/AlertID"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "alert_id",
            "camount",
            "check_cash_date",
            "event_date",
            "profile",
            "profile_address"
        ],
        "title": "AlertDetails"
    },
    "AlertID": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "subject": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "abc_id": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "abc_id",
            "id",
            "subject"
        ],
        "title": "AlertID"
    },
    "Profile": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Name"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "name"
        ],
        "title": "Profile"
    },
    "Name": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "first_name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "last_name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "middle_name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "middle_name"
        ],
        "title": "Name"
    },
    "ProfileAddress": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "street_address": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "city": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "zip_code": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "integer"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "city",
            "name",
            "state",
            "street_address",
            "zip_code"
        ],
        "title": "ProfileAddress"
    },
       "reviewcheck":{
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "alert_details": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/AlertDetails"
            },
            "alert_sub_type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "alert_type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "provider": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "view_date": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "alert_details",
            "alert_sub_type",
            "alert_type",
            "provider",
            "status",
            "view_date"
        ]
    },
    "AlertDetails": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "event_date": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time"
            },
            "account_number": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "check_start_number": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "integer"
            },
            "myprofile": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Myprofile"
            },
            "order_shipped_date": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
            },
            "myprofile_address": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/MyprofileAddress"
            },
            "quantity_ordered": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "integer"
            },
            "alert_id": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/AlertID"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "account_number",
            "alert_id",
            "check_start_number",
            "event_date",
            "myprofile",
            "myprofile_address",
            "order_shipped_date",
            "quantity_ordered"
        ],
        "title": "AlertDetails"
    },
    "AlertID": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "subject": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "abc_id": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "abc_id",
            "id",
            "subject"
        ],
        "title": "AlertID"
    },
    "Myprofile": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Name"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "name"
        ],
        "title": "Myprofile"
    },
    "Name": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "first_name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "last_name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "middle_name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "middle_name"
        ],
        "title": "Name"
    },
    "MyprofileAddress": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "street_address": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "city": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "zip_code": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "integer"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "city",
            "name",
            "state",
            "street_address",
            "zip_code"
        ],
        "title": "MyprofileAddress"
    }
```

}}

validation is not working for me, Example, in this schema I have provided the required field "alert_id",  if I remove this field in the JSON data, still the validation gets success instead of failing with some error

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/Tqh2XRMI.  ---> in this, I am keeping
**aaaprofile** instead of profile
**aaaalert_id** instead of alert_id

it should throw a validation error but I am not getting any validation error

Comment: Hello. What specificly is the problem. What do you want or expect to happen? Saying "validation is not working" does not tell us what validation you require.

Comment: For JSON Schema, you can find learing resources here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/ web based playgrounds here: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-web%20(online) and the helpful slack channel here: https://json-schema.org/slack (should you have questions that don't belong on StackOverflow)

Comment: @Relequestual validation is not working for me, Example ,in this schema I have provided the required field as "alert_id", if I remove this field in the JSON data , still the validation get success instead of failing with some error, I doubt that the way i am writing the schema might be wrong

Comment: Please edit your question to say what is happening, what you expect to happen, and why. =]

Comment: @Relequestual  

updated my question and expectations

Comment: If you have access to a Windows PC, I recommend to download and use the JSON Schema debugger of JSONBuddy from here https://www.json-buddy.com/blog/2022/05/11/introducing-the-new-json-schema-validation-debugger/ There is a free trial period and you should be able to check why the validation is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo  in line 4. It should be `oneOf` and not oneof:

```
"oneOf": [
  { "$ref":"#/definitions/checkchange" },
  { "$ref":"#/definitions/reviewcheck" }
]
```

The validation throws an error about the missing required property after this change.

Comment: That's a good catch, after changing from oneof to oneOf also still the validation is not working properly, May the schema might be wrongly written

Comment: At least I get the validation error about a missing "alert_id" and this is what you mentioned. What other errors do you expect?